# Date formats are different in Excel and OpenOffice

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have a XLS file created from Open-office.

When I open the file in Openoffice, it parse the date format as "dd/mm/yyyy"

If I open the file in MS office,  it parse the date format as "dd-mm-yyyy"

I just want to know, why there is difference in parsing the same (.xls) file in both applications?

Comment: What makes you think there is a difference in parsing the same date?  You've only described a difference in how a date is displayed.  And that has to do only with the format being used by the different programs.

Answer (score 0):

If the date uses the short date format, then no explicit format is stored in the `Excel` file. So how the date appears depends on the following:

For `OpenOffice` it depends on the [chosen language settings](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Choosing_language_settings). The used format `dd/mm/yyyy` is the short date format for English (UK) for example.

For `Microsoft Office` it depends on the [Windows regional settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989). There someone has chosen `dd-mm-yyyy` as the short date format.

Dependent on what settings are chosen in the system which opens the `Excel` file, the short date appear differently.

So if you need having the format explicitly stored in the `Excel` file, so it is not system dependent, you have to set it to another format apart form the short date format. Which is the short date format is not easy to see in `OpenOffice` format-cells-dialog. In `Excel` format-cells-dialog it is marked with a leading asterisk (*).